# Re-entering Israel after Student Visa expires?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, israel, study

My multiple entry student visa was issued on June 25th, 2012 and expires on June 24th, 2013.

I entered Israel on August 26th, 2012.

I am planning to leave Israel on June 13th (to Poland) and return approximately a month later in order to take my return flight home to the United States (I am a U.S. citizen); staying in Israel no longer than a week.

Will I be able to re enter Israel in order to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  You are a national of which country?

Comment: United States citizen

Comment: I was wondering if you had any problems returning to Israel with an expired student visa? I am planning on travelling to my home country (UK) soon and have been unable to renew my student visa in time, so I just wanted to know if I would be allowed back into Israel with an expired visa. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You will not be able to re-enter Israel on your expired student visa, but you can obtain an ordinary tourist visa (B/2) on arrival, which will be good for up to 90 days. If you can narrow your time to a few days, you might be issued a transit visa on arrival instead.

Provided you have not violated the terms of your student visa and meet the usual requirements (demonstrate onward transportation, have at least 6 months validity on your passport, and possess adequate funds to cover your expenses during the visit), you should not need to make any special arrangements before your departure from Poland.

As always, it's best to double-check with the Israeli embassy or consulate most convenient to you, as rules may change from time to time. But I'd venture that holding a U.S. passport is perhaps second only to an Israeli one for ease of travel to or through Israel.